# Get current cell and copy it to other sheet google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to copy 3 values from sheet1 to sheet2  using custom button on clicking on it.

I have on sheet1

```
  A        B        C      D      F       G
1 bbb      kkkk     12     2      3       my custom button here
2 hhhh     tttt     13     6      8       my custom button here
3 ttt      qqqq     16     1      4       my custom button here
```

And my sheet2

```
   A        B          C
1
```

What I want is when I click on `my custom button` I want to copy values FROM the clicked buttons row ex B1  C1 F1 in sheet1 to A1  B1  C1.

I tried this

```
function CopyPaste() {
   var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('sheet1');            
   var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('sheet2');   
   sheet1.getRange('G2').getValue().copyTo(sheet2.getRange('A45')) ;
   sheet1.getRange('I2').getValue().copyTo(sheet2.getRange('B45')) ;
   sheet1.getRange('K2').getValue().copyTo(sheet2.getRange('C45')) ;
}
```

BUT this getting always G2  I2  K2 and not the clicked row . AND from this I'm not getting the calculated value , I'm getting instead the formula script which I don't want. I want get just calculated values from sheet1 . they are calculated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that by "custom buttons" the question is referring to images with assigned scripts, they don't have an automatically assigned [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) like occurs with triggers like On Open among others.

One solution is to create a parameterized main function and a function for each set to parameters to be triggered by the "custom buttons". If you have a button for each row, and require to send the row number as parameter, you will need a function for each row.

Example

```
function customButton_row1() {
   CopyPaste(1);
}

function customButton_row2() {
   CopyPaste(2);
}

function CopyPaste(row) {
   var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('sheet1');            
   var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('sheet2');   
   sheet1.getRange('G' + row).getValue().copyTo(sheet2.getRange('A45')) ;
   sheet1.getRange('I' + row).getValue().copyTo(sheet2.getRange('B45')) ;
   sheet1.getRange('K' + row).getValue().copyTo(sheet2.getRange('C45')) ;
}
```